# Cannot catch AWS S3 exception

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, exception

I'm trying to get the filesize of an S3 object using the Stream API with the following code:

```
try{
    $fileSize = filesize("s3://".$bucket."/".$filename);
}catch(Aws\S3\Exception\NoSuchKeyException $e) {
    return false;
}
```

If the key doesn't exist I get the following error:

> [Tue Oct 13 23:03:32 2015] [error] [client 54.225.205.152] PHP Warning:  File or directory not found: s3://mybucket/myfile.jpg in /var/www/vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/Aws/S3/StreamWrapper.php on line 774
>
> [Tue Oct 13 23:03:32 2015] [error] [client 54.225.205.152] PHP Warning:  filesize(): stat failed for s3://mybucket/myfile.jpg in /var/www/api-dev/awsFunc.php on line 278
>
> [Tue Oct 13 23:03:32 2015] [error] [client 54.225.205.152] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Aws\S3\Exception\NoSuchKeyException: AWS Error Code: NoSuchKey, Status Code: 404, AWS Request ID: 4A6F1372301D02F7, AWS Error Type: client, AWS Error Message: The specified key does not exist., User-Agent: aws-sdk-php2/2.8.21 Guzzle/3.9.3 curl/7.22.0 PHP/5.3.10-1ubuntu3.19\n  thrown in /var/www/vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/Aws/Common/Exception/NamespaceExceptionFactory.php on line 91

So, although I explicitly try to catch the Aws\S3\Exception\NoSuchKeyException the system throws it anyway.

**UPDATE:**

I found the error. The exception should namespace should start with '\' instead of Aws, like that:

```
try{
    $fileSize = filesize("s3://".$bucket."/".$filename);
}catch(\Aws\S3\Exception\NoSuchKeyException $e) {
    return false;
}
```

I don't know though why when I `use` a namespace the namespace doesn't start with '\' but in the exception it needs it. I'd like someone to explain.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Handling errors in AWS PHP SDK 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15918746/handling-errors-in-aws-php-sdk-2)

Comment: I don't think it's duplicate, the answers in the above question suggest to use what I'm already using but the exception isn't caught

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ok so here is what worked for me:

```
use Aws\S3\Exception\S3Exception as S3;


try {
    $podcast = $this->uploadFileToS3($request);
} catch(S3 $e) {
    return $e->getMessage();
 }
```

In my case, i passed the message to a session flash like so:

```
 return redirect('dashboard/episode/create')->with('status', $e->getMessage());
```

So it all depends on how you want to use it.

```
try {
    $fileSize = filesize("s3://".$bucket."/".$filename);
} catch(S3 $e) {
    return $e->getMessage();
 }
```

Good Luck!

Answer (score 2):

This is the right way.

```
use Aws\Exception\AwsException;

try{
    // something
}catch(AwsException $e){
    echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you know why the namespace doesn't require to be declared in the global scope with the leading slash when using `use`, but inside the `catch` it requires the leading slash?

Comment: Maybe you haven't correctly declared the namespace in `use` line. If you did that there's non need for the leading slash in `catch`. My example works without it. Read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4849279/importing-classes-and-namespaces-in-php-what-difference-does-a-leading-backslas) maybe it can help you. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of `AWSException` class `getAwsErrorMessage()` method
So you could do

```
use Aws\S3\Exception\S3Exception;
 try {
     // Your Code       
 } catch (S3Exception $e) {
     return $e->getAwsErrorMessage();
 }
```